# include custom layouts with same child ids

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using a custom control that has a spinner in the relative layout. In my activity I have to use two of these custom controls. The problem is when accessing the spinner from the activity same id is returned.

code for custom control

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_white"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/bg_white"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_dropdown"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
    RelativeLayout rl_category,rl_subcategory;
    Spinner sp_category,sp_subcategory;

  rl_category=(CustomSpinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_category);
  rl_subcategory=(CustomSpinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_subcategory);
  sp_category=(Spinner) rl_category.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  sp_subcategory=(Spinner) rl_subcategory.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

If android doesn't differentiate these ids in same activity then how should I add multiple custom layouts in activity.

Answer (score 0):

In the same `xml` layout you cannot use same id twice. In very simple manner, you can declare two custom controls with different spinner id. You want to reuse the custom controls, do  it in other activities as your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare any id it has save in **R.java** class in a numeric pattern, so you declare any two or more widgets/layout with same name in same **XML** then it will return you same numeric result. you need to change the ID's.
hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a `id` in same xml file more than once.
To do so, you can include custom control layout multiple times in activity's xml.

Here, I have include the custom layout twice

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <include
    android:id="@+id/customControl1"
    layout="@layout/custom_layout"/>

   <include
    android:id="@+id/customControl2"
    layout="@layout/custom_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in **activity** code

```
sp_category=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.customControl1).findViewById(R.id.spinner);
sp_subcategory=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.customControl2).findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

**custom_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_white"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/bg_white"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_dropdown"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```